# NP-hard $k$-SAT variant with exactly $\ell$ occurrences per variable

Tags: reductions, np-hard, satisfiability, 3-sat

For the purpose of this post, let $k$-SAT be SAT with exactly $k$ literals per clause, as opposed to the more common meaning of at most $k$ literals per clause.

With the purpose of proving some problem NP-hard, I'd like to reduce from a $k$-SAT variant (which of course should remain NP-hard) in which each variable occurs exactly $\ell$ times in the formula.

I've tried to look up 3-SAT with exactly 3 occurrences of a variable, but [this paper](http://cedric.cnam.fr/%7Ebentzc/INITREC/Files/CB11.pdf) proves 3-SAT with at most 3 occurrences per variable is trivial, which includes my specific case of exactly 3 occurrences. (In fact, this is the case whenever $k = \ell$.)

All hope is not lost though, as in the same paper, it is proven that 3-SAT with at most $\ell$
occurrences per variable, with $\ell>3$ is NP-hard. I'm looking into the details of the reduction to see if by chance they have proved the specific case of exactly $\ell$ occurrences per variable to be NP-hard (which would extend to the general case of at most $\ell$ occurrences per variable), but wanted to ask this question here while searching:

**Does there exist an NP-hard $k$-SAT variant with exactly $\ell$ occurrences per variable?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of deciding the satisfiability of 3CNFs in which each variable occurs exactly 5 times is NP-complete (and even NP-hard to approximate), see Uriel Feige, [A threshold of $\ln n$ for approximating Set Cover](https://courses.cs.duke.edu/spring07/cps296.2/papers/p634-feige.pdf).

Comment: For anyone clicking on the link and wondering: MAX-SNP hardness implies NP hardness.